# SQL join two tables selecting only one ID

Tags: sql

I have the following problem and I have no idea of how to solve it...

We got 2 tables:

COMPANIES ESTIMATED

| id | name | estimation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMAZON | True |
| 2 | GOOGLE | True |
| 3 | FACEBOOK | True |

COMPANIES MIXED

| id | name | estimation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMAZON | False |
| 2 | GOOGLE | False |
| 3 | FACEBOOK | False |
| 4 | TESLA | False |

Well, I want to **JOIN BOTH TABLES but DONT REPEAT IDs. If an ID appears 2 times in the result table, I want to KEEP THE TRUE** one and discard the False one.

Example response I expected:

COMPANIES FINAL

| id | name | estimation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMAZON | True |
| 2 | GOOGLE | True |
| 3 | FACEBOOK | True |
| 4 | TESLA | False |

In this example you may think: "I add TESLA to first table, EZ" but is not the answer I am looking for. I need something like an OUTTER JOIN or something like that. Im trying but it's impossible for me.

Thanks guys.

Comment: What if true occurs twice? You would filter out using `where estimation = 'true'`.

Comment: UNION ALL, GROUP BY, MAX.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Will there be entries in the `Estimated` table that will NOT be in the `Mixed` table as well?

Comment: What is supposed to hapen when ID/name differ, say ID 1 = GOOGLE and ID 2 = AMAZON in the second table?

Comment: @JNevill COMPANIES ESTIMATED can have TRUE or FALSE, COMPANIES MIXED only has FALSES. What I want is, if in the COMPANIES FINAL two IDs are the same, maintain the COMPANIES ESTIMATED' field and discard the COMPANIES MIXED one.

Comment: @TanveerBadar TRUE never can occur twice. Otherwise, FALSE can occur twice but I want to keep the COMPANIES ESTIMATED field.

Comment: Im using MySQL, from AWS Athena.

Answer (score 4):

`UNION ALL` the tables. `GROUP BY` the result. Use `MAX()` to get true if available, otherwise false.

```
select id, name, max(estimation)
from
(
  select id, name, estimation from COMPANIES_ESTIMATED
  union all
  select id, name, estimation from COMPANIES_MIXED
) dt
group by id, name
```

Answer (score 2):

If for all records COMPANIES MIXED table `estimation = 'false'`
Next query can help:

```
SELECT * FROM COMPANIES_ESTIMATED
UNION
SELECT * FROM COMPANIES_MIXED WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM COMPANIES_ESTIMATED)
```

Otherwise

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(estimation) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM COMPANIES_ESTIMATED
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM COMPANIES_MIXED) AS all_companies
GROUP BY id, name;
```

Comment: That would be better with `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION [DISTINCT]`. And backticks around table names are not standard SQL. The only DBMS I know of allowing backticks on names are MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner agree. I've edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(estimated.id, mixed.id) AS id, 
  COALESCE(estimated.name, mixed.name) AS name, 
  COALESCE(estimated.estimation, mixed.estimation) AS estimation
FROM 
  estimated 
  FULL OUTER JOIN mixed
  ON estimated.id = mixed.id
ORDER BY
  id
```

Example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dc483a/1

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh it was for MSSQL but after the OP comments the ISNULL and bitwise is not required. So it should now be standard compliant.

Comment: ANSI SQL has column aliase after the expression, e.g. `COALESCE(estimated.id, mixed.id) AS id`. MS SQL Server supports this too - and it's portable! (`id` in `id = COALESCE(estimated.id, mixed.id)` will give ambiguous column error, according to ANSI SQL. id in the ORDER BY too.)

Comment: DBMS is MySQL on Athena.

Answer (score 1):

just to mix it up a bit you could do it with a full outer join.
not sure which rdbms you are using but here is one in sql server

```
select IIF(a.id>b.id, a.id, b.id) id,
IIF(a.name>b.name, a.name, b.name) Name,
IIF(a.estimation>b.estimation, a.estimation, b.estimation) estimation
from companies_estimated a
full outer join companies_mixed b
on (a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name);
```

here is the fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b87f66/13

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are other columns to bring along:

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number()
        over (partition by id order by estimation desc) rn
    from
    (
        select id, name, estimation, ... from COMPANIES_ESTIMATED
        union all
        select id, name, estimation, ... from COMPANIES_MIXED
    ) t
)
select * from data where rn = 1
```