# Join 2 tables but if IDs are repeated, maintain/keep the first table one

Tags: mysql, sql

I posted yesterday a similar question but I forgot to mention an important thing so i repeat it today:

We got 2 tables:

COMPANIES ESTIMATED

| id | name | estimation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMAZON | True |
| 2 | GOOGLE | True |
| 3 | FACEBOOK | True |

COMPANIES MIXED

| id | name | estimation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMAZON | False |
| 2 | GOOGLE | False |
| 3 | FACEBOOK | False |
| 4 | TESLA | False |
| 5 | APPLE | False |

Well, I just want to JOIN BOTH TABLES but if an ID appears 2 times, I want to keep the FIRST TABLE (COMPANIES ESTIMATED) one. I don't mind if is True or False, just keep the first tables result and discard the second's (COMPANIES MIXED) one.

Example response I expected:

COMPANIES FINAL

| id | name | estimation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AMAZON | True |
| 2 | GOOGLE | True |
| 3 | FACEBOOK | True |
| 4 | TESLA | False |
| 5 | APPLE | False |

NOTE: RDBM is MySQL, and one of my real project columns is a string array ([ES123,ABC456]) so COALESCE doesn't work...

Thanks all!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69471898/3706016

Comment: Hi again @jarlh, is your previous answer valid if i DON'T mind True/False (just wanna 1st tables results) and if it has STRING ARRAYS as fields?

Comment: Vlad Haidei's NOT EXISTS query will fits "just wanna 1st tables results". (But do UNION ALL.) The STRING ARRAYS issue should be reflected in sample data and expected result!

Comment: True! It worked! Thanks man, luv u <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select m.id, m.name, case when e.estimation is null then m.estimation 
     when m.estimation or e.estimation then true else false end
from companies_mixed m left join companies_estimated e on e.id = m.id;
```

Comment: Seems like OP wants full outer join. (Other sample data in OP's previous question.)